# Use Arrays to do "count sort" in VBA-excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to learn how to do count-sorting in excel-vba using arrays. I'm having some issue with the final step of actually doing the count sort (v1Sort and V2 Sort columns). This is the table so far

```
V1  V2  Bin  V1Count  PointerV1  V2Count  PointerV2  V1Sort  V2Sort
6   3   -1      2         2          1        1         ?       ?
7   2    0      3         5          4        5
1   6    1      4         9          4        9
5   3    2      5        14          5       14
6   0    3      2        16          2       16
9   7    4      4        20          2       18
7   9    5      4        24          4       22
8   6    6      2        26          4       26
2   4    7      4        30          1       27
8   3    8      1        31          2       29
4   2    9      0        31          2       31
1   3   10              
2   6                   
0  10                   
1   5                   
8   7                   
5   9                   
5  10                   
5   1                   
6   7                   
3   2                   
8   5                   
0   6                   
2   8                   
3   1                   
2   3                   
4   4                   
3   1                   
3   7                   
3   1                   
6   2
```

Here's my code so far without actually doing the final step of the count sort. I understand the concept fully but am finding it hard to use arrays to do the count sort.

````
Sub Count_Sorting()
 Const iOffData     As Integer = 1
 Const iOffPoint    As Integer = 2
 Const iOffPoint_2  As Integer = 3
 Dim iBin           As Integer
 Dim iData          As Integer
 Dim iPointerVector_1()  As Integer
 Dim iPointerVector_2()  As Integer
 Dim iPoint         As Integer
 Dim iRow           As Integer
 Dim iDataVector_1(32)   As Integer
 Dim iDataVector_2(32)   As Integer
 Dim iSortVector_1(1 To 50)       As Integer
 Dim iSortVector_2(1 To 50)       As Integer


 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(50, 8)).Clear
 ReDim iPointerVector_1(-1 To 11)
 ReDim iPointerVector_2(-1 To 11)

 Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "V1"
 Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = "V2"
 Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Bin"
 Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 4).Value = "V1Count"
 Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 5).Value = "PointerV1"
 Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 6).Value = "V2Count"
 Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 7).Value = "PointerV2"

 'Write bin numbers.
 For iRow = 2 To 13
   Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 3).Value = iRow - iOffPoint_2
 Next iRow

 'Read the values from Sheet1.
 For iRow = 2 To 32
   iDataVector_1(iRow) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 1).Value
   iDataVector_2(iRow) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 2).Value
 Next iRow


 '************************************************************
 'First we do the procedure for sorting Vector 1
 '************************************************************

 'Count the number of data points in each bin for Vector 1 .
 For iRow = 2 To 32
   iPointerVector_1(iDataVector_1(iRow)) = iPointerVector_1(iDataVector_1(iRow)) + 1
 Next iRow

For iBin = 0 To 10
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iBin + iOffPoint, 4).Value = iPointerVector_1(iBin)
Next iBin

 'Get cumulative counts, located in prior bins, in preparation for later
 're-reading of the data and decrementing of the pointers for Vector 1.
 For iBin = 0 To 10
   iPointerVector_1(iBin) = iPointerVector_1(iBin - 1) + iPointerVector_1(iBin)
 Next iBin
 For iBin = 0 To 10
   Sheets("SHeet1").Cells(iBin + iOffPoint, 5).Value = iPointerVector_1(iBin)
 Next iBin


 '

 '************************************************************
 'Now we do the procedure for sorting Vector 2
 '************************************************************

 'Count the number of data points in each bin for Vector 2.
 For iRow = 2 To 32
   iPointerVector_2(iDataVector_2(iRow)) = iPointerVector_2(iDataVector_2(iRow)) + 1
 Next iRow

For iBin = 0 To 10
Sheets("SHeet1").Cells(iBin + iOffPoint, 6).Value = iPointerVector_2(iBin)
Next iBin

 'Get cumulative counts, located in prior bins, in preparation for later
 're-reading of the data and decrementing of the pointers for Vector 2.
 For iBin = 0 To 10
   iPointerVector_2(iBin) = iPointerVector_2(iBin - 1) + iPointerVector_2(iBin)
 Next iBin
 For iBin = 0 To 10
   Sheets("SHeet1").Cells(iBin + iOffPoint, 7).Value = iPointerVector_2(iBin)
 Next iBin


```End Sub
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed get the idea about count sorting. What makes your implementation difficult is the way you organize your code. Probably the first thing to do is to define a `CountSort()` function which takes as input an array of values, and returns an array of the same values sorted. Now, I see that you want to output the contents of intermediate arrays used in the count sort function to cells of Sheet1. So, you could pass to the `CountSort()` function the row and column indexes where to output intermediate arrays. So, your function could look like this:

```
' Returns array of the values sorted.
Public Function CountSort(values() As Integer, rowIndex As Integer, columnIndex As Integer) As Integer()

End Function
```

To output the contents of an array to Sheet1 you can define a routine like:

```
' Print contents of array values in column columnIndex, starting at rowIndex going downwards.
Sub PrintArray(values() As Integer, rowIndex As Integer, columnIndex As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(values) - LBound(values)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowIndex + i, columnIndex).Value = values(LBound(values) + i)
    Next
End Sub
```

And the `CountSort()` function would look like:

```
' Returns array of the values sorted.
Public Function CountSort(values() As Integer, rowIndex As Integer, columnIndex As Integer) As Integer()

    ' Assuming values are in range [0 10].
    Dim bin(0 To 10) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Initialize bin to 0.
    For i = LBound(bin) To UBound(bin)
        bin(i) = 0
    Next

    PrintArray values, rowIndex, columnIndex

    ' Count number of occurrences of each value.
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        bin(values(i)) = bin(values(i)) + 1
    Next

    PrintArray bin, rowIndex, columnIndex + 1

    ' Find cumulative frequency.
    For i = LBound(bin) + 1 To UBound(bin)
        bin(i) = bin(i) + bin(i - 1)
    Next

    PrintArray bin, rowIndex, columnIndex + 2

    ' Build sorted array.
    Dim sorted() As Integer
    ReDim sorted(LBound(values) To UBound(values)) As Integer
    For i = UBound(values) To LBound(values) Step -1
        sorted(bin(values(i))) = values(i)
        bin(values(i)) = bin(values(i)) - 1
    Next

    PrintArray sorted, rowIndex, columnIndex + 3

    ' Return sorted array.
    CountSort = sorted

End Function
```

In VBA, it is always a good idea to use the `LBound()` and `UBound()` functions as they make your code independent of how arrays have been declared index-wise.

Comment: I'll try this out. My values go from 1 to 32 and are in both Vectors 1 and Vectors 2.

Comment: Yes, you can read them from Sheet1 into an array, and pass them to the `CountSort()` function. As I said in my answer, most of the difficulties you had are most likely due to code organization, variable naming, etc., that is why I tried to show you one way of better organizing code into functions to make coding easier.